# How to store a internal property in jquery-ui widget?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, widget, jquery-ui-widget-factory

I am programming a new jquery-ui widget from scratch.
I found the official 'how widget factory works' document.
(http://jqueryui.com/demos/widget/)

The widget itself works fine.
Now I want to store some values internally - is there a preferred way to do this?
All properties that are declared in options are public I think.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use plain old properties on `this`. For example, a basic widget will look something like this:

```
$.widget('some_name', {
    options: { /* ... */ },
    _create: function() {
        // ...
        this.internal_value = 11;
        // ...
    },
    frobnicate_by: function(this_much) {
        this.internal_value += this_much;
    }
    // ...
});
```

And you can set up your internal values as properties of `this` as desired. For example, the above sets `this.internal_value` to an initial value of 11 and `$(s).some_name('frobnicate_by', 23)` would change the `internal_value`.

You can see an example of an internal property in the example widget you linked to by looking for `this.changer`.

The `options` are used for things that can be configured when someone creates an instance of your widget. Internal settings don't need any special handling, they're just plain old object properties; one of the nice things about the widget factory is that it makes it easy to do normal OO things in your widgets.